# Is it possible to connect a wired network to two separate wireless networks via a client based bridge?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I have two new robots in our lab and I’m trying to figure out the best way to connect them to our existing network. Basically, the problem is as follows:

Both robots are running EdiMax wireless routers as part of their internal parts (Ideally, I would like to leave these untouched) that allow the robots to be connected to individually i.e. with a wireless adapter I can join a robot AP and ssh into it for control.

ROBOT1 – SSID1 – 192.168.0.2

ROBOT2 – SSID2 – 192.168.0.3

MAIN NETWORK - 192.168.1.10 or wired

[image: ([See here][1] for diagram)]

The problem is that I need to communicate to both robots simultaneously from another machine which is attached to our main network. I have an old Linksys WRT150N router upgraded with the DD-WRT firmware lying around which I can directly connect (wired) to our existing framework.

Is it possible to use this router as a client which connects to both robot SSID’s? Both robots would ideally be able to communicate to each other and the master PC.

If not, I would appreciate any insights into a better solution.

Comment: How untouched do the routers have to be? Because it seems like the straightforward answer here would be to set them to bridge / extender mode for the main wifi.

Comment: Or buy two cheap wifi USB sticks for each lab computer :D

Comment: The robots are running software called ROS (Robot Operating System) which is reliant on the IP infrastructure for its protocols and various accessories (ip camera). I didn't want to touch the routers as I'm unsure how many file systems would be affected (per robot). Though it might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never tried it, but it should work, at least, theoretically.  Here is what I would do, get another, cheap WiFi card, maybe a USB (assuming you already have one build in) and hook up one WiFi card to one robot and another to another and you can wire in to your wired network.

Comment: I've tried this already with two wifi dongles. Unfortunately, the robots need to be able to communicate to each other in the event of multi-robot tasks which this setup does not allow for and I also need the possibility to communicate to both robots from the same control script.

Comment: @vincent So sorry for the delay in my response.  Why can't you bring them both to your 192.168.1.x network?  I would assume you can change IPs in the robots themselves and if it fails, I would assume you can do a hard reset.  I would think it would work similarly to when a DHCP issues an IP address for your computer on a network.  Just make sure you get correct Gateway and DNS of your network.  You can also make those IP permanent by make DHCP reservations if you have robots' MAC addresses.